# How to update a specific item of an array in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this value stored in my key, value

Now on my HTML DOM, I add some data [you can give example using any variable] and I want to update the `description:` parameter of the array below, can you guide me how can I simply update its value with any variable's value as example

`key - Section283`

value -

```
{
    "subtitle": "",
    "description": "<p>We are glad to hear from you!</p>",
    "id": "689",
    "title": "footer",
    "sectionType": "283",
    "latitude": "0",
    "longitude": "0",
    "tags": "",
    "userId": "32",
    "internalLink": "menu-lam"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update specific key value of the local storage array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191832/how-do-i-update-specific-key-value-of-the-local-storage-array)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191832/how-do-i-update-specific-key-value-of-the-local-storage-array

Comment: You do not have an array at all. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be clear that you do not have an array at all. What you are showing is an object. In plain JavaScript, the key names do not need to be quoted unless they have spaces in their names. With objects, updating one of its properties is easy:

```js
// Note the the property names do not need to be quoted unless they contain spaces:
var myObject = {
        subtitle: "",
        description: "<p>We are glad to hear from you!</p>",
        id: "689",
        title: "footer",
        sectionType: "283",
        latitude: "0",
        longitude: "0",
        tags: "",
        userId: "32",
        internalLink: "menu-lam"
    }
    
    // Getting property value out of an object:
    console.log("Original value of \"description\" property: " + myObject.description);
    
    // Changing property value:
    myObject.description = "Something New";
    
    // Getting new value:
    console.log("Current value of \"description\" property: " + myObject.description);
```

When you need to store something like this in `localStorage`, the object must be turned into a `string` (because that's the only data type `localStorage` can store). You can easily do this with the native `JSON` object, like this:

```js
        var myObject = {
            subtitle: "",
            description: "<p>We are glad to hear from you!</p>",
            id: "689",
            title: "footer",
            sectionType: "283",
            latitude: "0",
            longitude: "0",
            tags: "",
            userId: "32",
            internalLink: "menu-lam"
        }
        
        console.log("Original type for \"myObject\": " + typeof myObject);
        
        // Convert object to JSON
        var jObj = JSON.stringify(myObject);
        
        // Check converted type:
        console.log("Type for \"myObject\": " + typeof jObj);
```

Once the JSON string is created you can store it in `localStorage` like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("myData", jObj);
```

Then, to retrieve the data, you'd write:

```
var jsonString = localStorage.getItem("myData");
```

And finally, you need to convert the string back to an object and then you can use it normally:

```js
// This sets up what you'd get back from localStorage:
var localStorageString = `{
    "subtitle": "",
    "description": "<p>We are glad to hear from you!</p>",
    "id": "689",
    "title": "footer",
    "sectionType": "283",
    "latitude": "0",
    "longitude": "0",
    "tags": "",
    "userId": "32",
    "internalLink": "menu-lam"
}`;


// Convert the string back to an object
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorageString);

// Use the object as normal:
obj.description = "Something New";
console.log(obj.description);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice reply, this gave me a clear picture of what i wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to set the localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem(key, 'Section283');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hii, after setting the local storage how can i update a key name ? please advise

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm thinking.  Access your value using your key and then convert it to a Javascript Object and update it's description property.  Then convert the json object back to a string and use the key with the Array to set (essentially overwrite) the value.  Stab in the dark here.

```
var jsonObj = json.parse(yourArray['Section283']);
jsonObj.description = 'Whatever you want here';
yourArray['Section283'] = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```